# QTreeView not displaying model

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtreeview

I am using Qt4 and I am trying to display a model with a QTreeView. The model that I have is composed of several batch process that each batch has some elements and each element has some childs (the elements of the same batch have the same number of childs, but I do not think that is relevant for the problem). Similar to this:

```
+
|
+-+ Batch_0
|     +
|     |
|     +-+ Element_0
|     |     +
|     |     |
|     |     +-+ Child_0
|     |     |
|     |     +-+ Child_1
|     |     |
|     |     +-+ Child_2
|     |
|     +-+ Element_1
|     |     +
|     |     |
|     |     +-+ Child_0
|     |     |
|     |     +-+ Child_1
|     |     |
|     |     +-+ Child_2
|     |
|     +-+ Element_2
|           +
|           |
|           +-+ Child_0
|           |
|           +-+ Child_1
|           |
|           +-+ Child_2
|
+-+ Batch_1
      +
      |
      +-+ Element_0
      |     +
      |     |
      |     +-+ Child_0
      |
      +-+ Element_0
            +
            |
            +-+ Child_0
```

My widget is:

```
class QMainWidget : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit QMainWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~QMainWidget();

public slots:

    void load();
    void load2();

private:

    Ui::QMainWidget *ui;

    QDataItemTree* tree_view_model_;

    int n_loaded_;
};
```

With implementation:

```
QMainWidget::QMainWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),n_loaded_(0),
    ui(new Ui::QMainWidget)
{
    // Set up Ui
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Data tree
    tree_view_model_ = new QDataItemTree("Root");
    ui->treeView->setModel(tree_view_model_);

    // Connect load
    connect(ui->addElementsLoad_pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(load()));
    connect(ui->addElementsLoad2_pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(load2()));
}

QMainWidget::~QMainWidget()
{
    delete ui;
    delete tree_view_model_;
}

void QMainWidget::load()
{
    // How many elements to add
    int n_elements = QInputDialog::getInt(this,"Elements","How many elemtns?",10);

    // How many childs per element
    int n_childs_per_element = QInputDialog::getInt(this,"Elements","How many elemtns?",10);

    // Add batch to tree
    QDataItem* batch = tree_view_model_->addBatch(n_loaded_);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++)
    {
        QDataItem* element = tree_view_model_->addBatchElement(i,batch);
        for (int j = 0; j <= n_childs_per_element; j++)
        {
            tree_view_model_->addBatchElementChild(j,element);

        }
    }
    n_loaded_++;
    ui->treeView->setModel(tree_view_model_);

}

void QMainWidget::load2()
{
    // How many elements to add
    int n_elements = QInputDialog::getInt(this,"Elements","How many elemtns?",10);

    // How many childs per element
    int n_childs_per_element = QInputDialog::getInt(this,"Elements","How many elemtns?",10);

    // Add batch to tree
    tree_view_model_ = new QDataItemTree("Root");
    QDataItem* batch = tree_view_model_->addBatch(n_loaded_);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++)
    {
        QDataItem* element = tree_view_model_->addBatchElement(i,batch);
        for (int j = 0; j <= n_childs_per_element; j++)
        {
            tree_view_model_->addBatchElementChild(j,element);

        }
    }
    n_loaded_++;
    ui->treeView->setModel(tree_view_model_);

}
```

My problem is that when I try to add things to the model, it is only displayed if I use the function `load2()` but not with `load()`. The only difference between the two functions is that in `load2()` I create a new model each time it is called instead of adding elements to the model that has already set as the tree view model (see the code, avoid commenting on the memory leak, I already know it). I cannot create a new model every time because I want to add things to the existing model, not create a new one.

The simplified version of what I am trying to do can be found [here](https://github.com/apalomer/QTreeView_example).

I have read [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html) tutorial to be able to implement what I want.

Comment: could you revise or clarify your paragraph " ...In load2() I create a new model each time it is called  ...  ... I cannot create a new model every time because I want to add things"

Comment: The function that actually works, `load2()`, creates a new model every time it is called: `tree_view_model_ = new QDataItemTree("Root");`. However, this is not an option for me because I want to create an empty model in the constructor, and then, keep adding what I call `batch` every time I press a button. I did the part that creates a new model each time to show that the model tree actually works. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: `load()` should invoke when you press  addElementsLoad_pushButton .. this is what you did in the `connect()` statement .. hence can you debug what actually happens when you press that button .. does the slot `load()` invoke but without doing whats expected?

Comment: @MohammadKanan I know how `connect()` work. I have developped several UI. The funcion `load()` is called and executed properly. However, the `QTreeView` does not update the model that displays (it stays blank).

Comment: Its not a matter of what I or you know :) .. sometimes we foolishly mess tiny things my friend. I think it can be updating the view after load() finishes its work ..

Comment: How can I make the QTreeView update after `load()` finishes its work?

Comment: your code is using QDataItemTree .. there is no reference to it in qt ! may be they stopped it  ... even in the simple example it is not used .. this is a difficulty related to QT4 .. I wish I could help

Comment: QDataItemTree is my model implementation inheriting from QAbstractItemModel

Comment: Ok, this is what i suspected (the Q prefix is always QT items) I would assume your implementation is similar to the example

Comment: The problem could be in implementation of data() and flags() method of your QDataItemTree class.

Comment: Fast, but not good, solution is to call beginResetModel() and endResetModel() after adding items.

Comment: @AndreySemenov you should not call beginResetModel(), that's not optimal since you reload the entire model in the view

Comment: @eyllanesc i know that. that's why i wrote "but not good". This solution could helps to determine what doesn't work: notificayion about model changes or data-providing methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because they have not notified the view that you have added new elements, for this you must call `beginInsertRows()` and `endInsertRows()` but for that you need to obtain the `QModelIndex` associated with the `QDataItem`, for this I have implemented the following method:

```
QModelIndex QDataItemTree::indexFromItem(QDataItem *item){
    if(item == rootItem || item == NULL)
        return QModelIndex();
    QDataItem *parent = item->parentItem();

    QList<QDataItem *> parents;

    while (parent && parent!=rootItem) {
        parents<<parent;
        parent = parent->parentItem();
    }
    QModelIndex ix;
    parent = rootItem;
    /*for(auto ch: parents){
        ix = index(ch->row(), 0, ix);
    }*/

    for(int i=0; i < parents.count(); i++){
        ix = index(parents[i]->row(), 0, ix);
    }
    ix = index(ix.row(), 0, ix);
    return ix;
}
```

Then this method is used when adding items:

```
QDataItem* QDataItemTree::addBatch(int number)
{
    QString name = "Batch_"+QString::number(number);
    QList<QVariant> d;
    d<<name;
    QDataItem* batch = new QDataItem(d,rootItem);
    beginInsertRows(indexFromItem(rootItem), rootItem->childCount(), rootItem->childCount());
    rootItem->appendChild(batch);
    endInsertRows();
    return batch;
}

QDataItem* QDataItemTree::addBatchElement(int number, QDataItem* parent)
{
    QString name = "Element_"+QString::number(number);
    QList<QVariant> d;
    d<<name;
    QDataItem* element = new QDataItem(d,parent);
    beginInsertRows(indexFromItem(parent), parent->childCount(), parent->childCount());
    parent->appendChild(element);
    endInsertRows();
    return element;
}

QDataItem* QDataItemTree::addBatchElementChild(int number, QDataItem* parent)
{
    QString name = "Child_"+QString::number(number);
    QList<QVariant> d;
    d<<name;
    QDataItem* element_child = new QDataItem(d,parent);
    beginInsertRows(indexFromItem(parent), parent->childCount(), parent->childCount());
    parent->appendChild(element_child);
    endInsertRows();
    return element_child;
}
```

In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48243686-QTreeView_example) is the complete code.

In the following link there is a detailed explanation of how to create editable models not only in the information that shows but the creation of rows and columns:

- http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#an-editable-model